# Is there any way to get at the items inside a UIElementCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have a bunch of CheckBoxes in a grid. I want to access them so that I can set them to checked or unchecked according to a registry value on start up.

I have got the Grid's children as a UIElementCollection, and Filtered out other Types.. However, there doesn't seem to be any way of accessing the data stored inside the collection. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIElementCollection` is [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) so you can just loop over it...

```
foreach( UIElement child in myUIElementCollection)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify search of controls by type or whatever you can use `VisualTreeHelper` and traverse elements in this way:

```
foreach (UIElement childElement in myUIElementCollection) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(childElement); i++)
  {
     DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
     var checkBox = child as CheckBox;
     if (checkBox != null)
     {
         // update it
     }
  }
}
```

BTW, why just not to expose boolean property like `IsRegistryValueFound` and just bind it to `CheckBox.IsChecked` property in `XAML`?

Comment: The Registry Value is a bitmask, I need to check each bit and set checkboxes to checked or unchecked accordingly.

Comment: I ended up using 

if(o is a)
{

}

To check for the elements I wanted.

Comment: @Luke: but keep in mind that this approach (uiElement is CheckBox) will not look into the child controls of particular uiElement